# How do I make a block able to be broken by fists?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to create a minecraft map at first I tried using an armor stand but then I learned there wasn't a way to summon a killable armor stand so I tried a block.

I am using a cracked stone brick for a secret spot with a chest in it and I want the block to be broken in one single punch (I will be fine if there isn't a way to do that)

The problem here is I know you can make it possible to break a block with tools but what I want to do is make it so that the player can break it without using anything other than their bare fists.

Is there a way to do this or am I going to be forced to use tools?

Answer (score 2):

Put an allow block underneath the block you want to break.

Edit: If needed you can give them haste.

DISCLAIMER: This will cause all other blocks above the allow to be destroyed as well. For more info visit the wiki article:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Allow_and_Deny